# iOS: Is it possible to enable LED flash for Alerts programmatically?

Tags: ios, ios9, accessibility, ios10, programmatic-config

Is it possible in **iOS** to enable the accessibility setting "Led Flash for Alerts" programmatically?

[image]

Comment: I don't think that you can. Almost settings must be done by the user.